# Passing ID to another form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

im trying to pass the information of a specific data to be edited in another form which is edit_doc.php. However, when i click "Edit" it doesnt seem to work. Only edit_doc.php opens but the information the does not appear. Is ther any mistake in the codes? Please help.

[php]

```
  echo "<table border='1'>
    <th>File Reference No.</th>
    <th>File Name</th>
    <th>Owner</th>
    <th>iShare URL</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Borrow</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>";
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))  
    {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>". $rows['file_ref']  ."</td>";
      echo "<td>". $rows['file_name'] ."</td>";
      echo "<td>". $rows['owner'] ."</td>";
      echo "<td>". $rows['url']    ."</td>";
      echo "<td><a href=edit_doc.php?id=<?php $['id']; ?>" . "Edit" . "</a></td>";

      echo "</tr>";

    }
   echo "</table>";
```

[/php]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the link is wrong, you are putting a `<?php` in a string, which will not be parsed by php. furthermore, the line must look something like this:

```
echo "<td><a href=edit_doc.php?id=" . $rows['id'] . ">Edit</a></td>";
```

consider using an editor with syntax highlighting.

Comment: do you understand the difference between your line and my line?

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

- You are using php tags inside php tags:
- Missing `$rows` variable to get the db row value for id field

Here is the fixed version:

```
echo "<td><a href=edit_doc.php?id=" . $rows['id'] . ">Edit</a></td>";
```